# Center of preimage of open ball

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I have a function $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and am told that if $Y = B(x, r)$ is open, then $f^{-1}(Y)$ is an open ball $B'$ as well. Can I say anything about the center of the preimage? Namely, is it true that $B'$ has the center $f^{-1}(x)$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

Take the ball $Y=(1,2)$ with center $y=\frac{3}{2}$

Take $f(x)=x^2$ for $x \geq 0$ and $f(x)=0$ for $x<0$ ,so inverse image is 
 $f^{-1}(1,2)=(1,\sqrt{2})$ which has center $\frac{\sqrt{2}+1}{2}$

But $f^{-1}(\frac{3}{2}) \neq \frac{\sqrt{2}+1}{2}$

Comment: The original question states that we are told that for our $f$ the inverse images of open balls are open balls, so this example, as written, isn't technically a counter example (as the inverse image isn't a ball). You could restrict the domain to $[0,\infty)$ and it would work, or switch from $x^2$ to $x^3$.

Comment: @JonathanZ i edited,yu are right..i did not see the ''if'' in the question.

Comment: Ha, and I didn't notice that that the function was specified to be defined on all of $\mathbb{R}$, which is why I suggested restricting the domain, as opposed to re-defining it like you did. Sometimes I get the heart of an idea and blow past those little details in the rush to write it down.